# Unable to drag a button element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on. It's a web application with an interface that partly exists out of drag 'n drop elements.

The issue is that the draggable div elements work fine but the button elements won't engage the drag in Firefox but they do work in Chrome. I think this might have something to do with the way Firefox handles the already existing events of the button, which is probably different than how Chrome does this.

I know I can use jQuery UI instead but this project does not allow me to.

Here is a jsfiddle of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/MJN6c/6/

Does anyone know how I can get the drag events to trigger on buttons in Firefox?

The code:

```
var stage = document.querySelector('#drop');
var btnsAni = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-ani');

[].forEach.call(btnsAni, function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
    btn.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd, false);
});

stage.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
stage.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
stage.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
stage.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop, false);

function dragStart(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);

    return false;
}

function dragEnd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

    return false;
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}

function dragDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    alert("Dropped!");
}
```

Comment: what about regular jQuery?

Comment: That might be a possibility, I'll have to ask. But if that's the only (decent) solution than I don't think it will be much of a problem.

Comment: It's a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646823), I couldn't find any work-arounds for that... Any updates on your side?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug with FF, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568313.
As an aside, all XUL elements are "draggable" by default.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#draggableattribute

Comment: What does it mean that all XUL elements are "draggable" by default, or how it is useful in this context? :)

Answer (score 3):

In few words: this is the issue with Firefox, not with your code. Drag event doesn't fire on button, but fires on div.

**I could handle this issue in few steps:**

1) Add a wrapper for button

2) Add ::after pseudo-element to the wrapper

3) Stretch ::after to fill the parent:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;

   &:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

This way ::after will be out of normal flow and wrapper's size will be calculated by button's size (as usually). If the button doesn't have defined z-index, ::after will be placed automatically on top of the button (on z-axis). This will cause firing of drag events on wrapper, not the button. And the issue is solved!

You probably would like to fix some styles after adding a wrapper (for example, you have to move :hover and :focus pseudo-classes to the wrapper).