# Draggable button in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, cross-browser, draggable

Is it possible to make a `<button>` (`<input type="button">`) work with HTML5 drag and drop in Mozilla Firefox (while still being clickable)?

The following snippet works in Google Chrome but the button and div with button cannot be dragged Mozilla Firefox (unless the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed down, no idea about mobile):

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener(
  "dragstart",
  function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "myDiv")
  }
);

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener(
  "dragstart",
  function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "myButton")
  }
);

document.getElementById("myDivWithButton").addEventListener(
  "dragstart",
  function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "myDivWithButton")
  }
);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" draggable="true">Div</div>
<button id="myButton" draggable="true">Button</button>
<div id="myDivWithButton" draggable="true"><button>Div with Button</button></div>
```

I used `draggable="true"` and `dataTransfer.setData`, is there something I missed? Is there some sensible workaround?

(If you want to know what I need this for:  I have something which can be either dragged at a certain position or set at the default position [center of current view], my idea was to do both through the button [d&d → choose position, click → default position]. I know that I guess I could try to format a `<div>` to make it look like a `<button>` or simply split the control into two elements but I'd rather not.)

Comment: This discussion has already been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967786/unable-to-drag-a-button-element-in-firefox). There seems to be a bug in FF which prevents dragging of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tricky solution:

```html
<label draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '')">
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" style="pointer-events: none" onclick="console.log(event)">
</label>
```

Wrap input with a draggable label and set `pointer-events` CSS property to `none`. Using this method, your button will be interactive and draggable.

Answer (score 8):

There is already a bug on Firefox where you can't drag a button. 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568313

However you can drag your div containing button (which is not draggable right now) using 'after' pseudo class.
Example:

```js
document.getElementById("myDivWithButton").addEventListener(
  "dragstart",
  function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "myDivWithButton")
  }
);
```

```css
.frontdrop {
   position: relative;
}

.frontdrop:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDivWithButton" class="frontdrop" draggable="true"><button>Div with Button</button></div>
```

Comment: While this enables the dragging, it actually stops the button from being interactive. Try clicking the button.

Answer (score 3):

From others, I came to know that your issue is because of a bug exists in Firefox. I suggest you to implement custom listeners to imitate drag event.
My solution is as follows:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

var btnPressed = false;

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  btnPressed = true;
  px = e.clientX;
  py = e.clientY;
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  btnPressed = false;
})

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  btn.style.MozTransform = "";
  btn.style.WebkitTransform = "";
  btn.style.opacity = 1;
})

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(btnPressed) {
    dx = e.clientX - px;
    dy = e.clientY - py;
    btn.style.opacity = 0.85;
    btn.style.MozTransform = "translate(" + dx + "px, " + dy + "px)";
    btn.style.WebkitTransform = "translate(" + dx + "px, " + dy + "px)";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Drag Me</button>
```

I know its not perfect. Hard-coding is the only way to resolve this issue until Firefox fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a little ledge that is draggable next to the button.

```
.frontdrop:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 20;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width="1";
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
}
```